# Improving function that parses string and returns first integer present

Tags: javascript

This exercise is from jshero.com.

Write a function parseFirstInt that takes a string and returns the first integer present in the string. If the string does not contain an integer, you should get NaN.

Here is my working solution. I'm posting in hopes of receiving pointers on how I could have written the code more effectively.

```
function parseFirstInt(str) {
    if (Number.isNaN(str) === true) {
        return NaN;
    } else {
        let searchFrom = str.search(/[-+]?[0-9]+/g);
        let searched = str.substr(searchFrom);
        return parseInt(searched, 10);
    };
}
```

Example: parseFirstInt('No. 10') should return 10 and parseFirstInt('Babylon') should return NaN.
parseFirstInt('No. -3) should return -3.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have either misunderstood the task, or misunderstood `Number.isNaN`. In any case the `if` doesn't do anything usefull. `Number.isNaN` returns `true` only when the value is exactly `NaN`, which is not a valid input for your function anyway.

Then you are not checking if `search()` isn't matching anything (and thus `searchFrom` is `-1`). It doesn't really matter, because `substr(-1)` simply returns the last character, but it would make the code better to understand.

Use `const` instead of `let` when the value doesn't change.

Personnally I'd use `.match()` instead of `.search()`, because it returns the matched string directly (in an array):

```
function parseFirstInt(str) {
  // Check if the paramter is a object with the method `match`
  if (!str.match) {
    return NaN; 
  }
  const match = str.match(/[-+]?[0-9]+/);
  if (match && match[0]) {
    return parseInt(match[0], 10);
  }
  return NaN;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I just have one question. Could you please explain what is happening here (!str.match) in the code you provided?